# Validation Confirmation - Change Confirmation From String to Integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activerecord

I'm using Rail's ActiveRecord Validation Confirmation to validate an id. I have two form fields, `cbiz_id` and `cbiz_id_confirmation`, so that the fields receive exactly the same content.

`cbiz_id` is an integer and ActiveRecord makes `cbiz_id_confirmation` a string.

Is there a way to validate `cbiz_id_confirmation` as an integer?

```
validates :cbiz_id, confirmation: true, presence: { if: :has_any_qapps_role?, notice: I18n.t('messages.updated') }
```

I've attempted a number of things such as:

```
before_validation :change_cbiz_id_confirmation_to_integer

def change_cbiz_id_confirmation_to_integer
 :cbiz_id_confirmation.to_i
end
```

I'm new to Ruby and Rails, so foundational explanations are appreciated!

Comment: What is the column type of `cbiz_id_confirmation`? If it is set to a string, that is why ActiveRecord is changing it. Do you want it to always be an integer?

Comment: cbiz_id_confirmation isn't a column. It's only a field that gets validated against cbiz id. ActiveRecord recognizes cbiz_id_confirmation as a string.

Comment: So it is a field that you made a custom `attr_accessor` for in your model?

Comment: You have several problems. 1. Your code is incomplete. Please provide more context. 2. Your method name says `..._to_string` but inside the method you call `to_i`, which tries to cast the symbol `:cbiz_id_confirmation` to an integer, which would be an error since symbols can't be cast to integers.

Answer (score 1):

Rails converts `cbiz_id` because it looks at the DB can sees that the column is an integer. Since there's no column for `cbiz_id_confirmation`, Rails doesn't have any type data, and the default type for any form submission (since form encoding and query params have no types) is a string.

Your `change_cbiz_id_confirmation_to_string` should work, but you're calling `to_i` on a symbol. You want just `cbiz_id_confirmation.to_i` (no leading `:`). Also, perhaps that method should end in `to_integer`.

If you want to ensure `cbiz_id_confirmation` is an integer even outside of validations, you can write a setter method that does the conversion for you.

```
attr_reader :cbiz_id_confirmation
def cbiz_id_confirmation=(value)
  @cbiz_id_confirmation = Integer(value)
rescue TypeError
  @cbiz_id_confirmation = nil
end
```

`Integer(value)` will raise an exception if the value cannot be converted (eg. it is `nil` or the word `"ham"`), so the `rescue` block makes this act like Rails and treat invalid data as `nil`. You can also use `value.to_i`, which that will coerce `nil` and `"ham"` to `0`, or just let the exception happen and handle the problem elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue with the following code:

```
attr_accessor :current_user_qapps_role, :cbiz_id_confirmation

validates :cbiz_id, confirmation: true, presence:true, if: :has_any_qapps_role?

def cbiz_id_confirmation=(val)
 @cbiz_id_confirmation = val.to_i
end
```

Answer (score -2):

You can easily create a custom validation rule like this, but there's probably some more elegant solution to your problem if I'd understand the context:

```
validate :cbiz_matches

def cbiz_matches
  errors.add(:cbiz_id, "ID's don't match") unless self.cbiz_id.to_i == self.cbiz_id_confirmaton.to_i
end
```

Comment: This is not enough. Rails custom validations like this need to manipulate the `errors` on a specific model. Check out the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validate) to how this should be done.